# Dust.js client-side rendering issue with precompiled template

Tags: javascript, dust.js, client-side-templating

I'm attempting test a simple client-side render with a pre-compiled dust template, but when I attempt to render, dust complains that it can't find my template:

```
[DUST WARN]: Chunk error [Error: Template Not Found: basicName] thrown. Ceasing to render this template.
```

My page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dust-full-2.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="basicName.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dustContainer"></div>
    <script>
        var json_payload = { "name": {
            "firstName" : "Brock",
            "lastName" : "Sampson"
        }};
        var dustContainerDiv = document.getElementById("dustContainer");

        dust.render("basicName", json_payload, function(err, out) {
                dustContainerDiv.innerHTML = out;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my template file (basicName.tl):

```
<p>{name.firstName}</p><p>{name.lastName}</p>
```

Compiles to this (basicName.js):

```
(function(){dust.register("basicName.tl",body_0);function body_0(chk,ctx){return chk.write("<p>").reference(ctx.getPath(false, ["name","firstName"]),ctx,"h").write("</p><p>").reference(ctx.getPath(false, ["name","lastName"]),ctx,"h").write("</p>");}return body_0;})();
```

I've tested this same template/payload/html using client-side template compilation and everything works fine.  What am I missing in order to be able to use pre-compiled templates?

Comment: stupid idea: what if you do `dust.render('basicName.tl', ...`

Answer (score 2):

If you take a closer look at compiled dust template, there is a line of code:

```
... dust.register("basicName.tl", ...
```

This line of code adds compiled template under key "basicName.tl" into `dust.cache`.

Under the hood `dust.render` will try to find given template name in `dust.cache`

Code below won't work since dust won't find "basicName" template in `dust.cache`:

```
dust.render("basicName", json_payload, function(err, out) {
...
```

Calling it like so should work:

```
dust.render("basicName.tl", json_payload, function(err, out) {
...
```